# Change class propery in JS - better performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two classes that I need to change color property on the fly.
The problem is the code I wrote is very very slow because those classes appear more then 100 times in my code.

Any suggestions hot make this code performance better?

```
if (mainColor) {
    var elColors = document.querySelectorAll('.color')
    elColors.forEach(el => el.style.color = mainColor)
    var elBgColors = document.querySelectorAll('.bg-color')
    elBgColors.forEach(el => el.style.backgroundColor = mainColor)
}
```

(the mainColor is comeing from the user input)

Comment: how slow ? .. like in `ms`

Comment: Just hardcode it in CSS.

Comment: Does it speed up if you switch the `elColors.forEach` line and `var elBgColors` line? (i.e. so you have `var... var... forEach... forEach`?)

Comment: use a class and use jquery to add or remove classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For high performance, don't set the style for each one.

Just assign a new class to the **parent node**.

For example:

**In dynamic way - JavaScript:**

```
var styles = document.querySelector('head style#dynamic'),
    sheet;

if (!styles) {
    styles = document.createElement('style');
    styles.id = 'dynamic';
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(styles);
}

sheet = styles.sheet;
sheet.insertRule("body.mainTheme .color { color: red; }", 0);
sheet.insertRule("body.mainTheme .bg-color { background-color: blue }", 0);

if (!document.body.className.match(/(^|\s)mainTheme(\s|$)/s)) {
    document.body.className = document.body.className + " mainTheme";
}
```

**In static way - JavaScript Part:**

```
// jQuery: $('body').addClass('mainTheme');
if (!document.body.className.match(/(^|\s)mainTheme(\s|$)/s)) {
    document.body.className = document.body.className + " mainTheme";
}
```

**In static way - CSS Part:**

```
.mainTheme .color {
    color: red;
}
.mainTheme .bg-color {
    background-color: blue
}
```

Comment: I agree with this answer. you can create multiple themes in this way.

Comment: What about the dynamic color?

Comment: @Mamun sheet.insertRule()

Comment: You should add that in the answer....because OP mentioned about the dynamic part...

Comment: Using [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) would certainly be cleaner than inserting different rules like you do.

Comment: @Kaiido But Internet Explorer doesn't support.

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted a good answer, it's worth adding a further alternative which takes advantage of CSS custom properties; here we update a custom property (a 'CSS variable') in one place and that change is reflected everywhere that custom property is used:

```js
function updateColors(mainColor) {
  if (mainColor) {
    let root = document.querySelector(':root');

    root.style.setProperty('--customColor', mainColor);
  }
}

document.querySelector('input[type=color]').addEventListener('input', function(){
  updateColors(this.value);
});
```

```css
:root {
  --customColor: red;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

div.color {
  color: var(--customColor);
}

div.bg-color {
  background-color: var(--customColor);
}
```

```html
<label><input type="color" /></label>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="color">'color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
<div class="bg-color">'bg-color'</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer. :)